# SSH tunnel and corporate proxy

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, tunnel

The scenario is as follows:

2 computers (PC1 & PC2)
Both access internet using an HTTP Proxy that requires authentication.

I SSH to PC2 from PC1 using:

```
ssh -D 8080 user@PC2_IP -v
```

The tunnel is created, but when I try to access the internet (Firefox) in PC1 using 127.0.0.1:8080 as socks4/socks5 proxy it just doesn't work.

What am I missing?

I have tried different ports. Also, I tried it at home and it works, but the difference is that there is no proxy.

How can I tell PC1 using an SSH tunnel to access PC2's internet?

- I have root access in both PC's
- The OS is Debian 6.0.4 in both PC's

Verbose parameter output when accessing a website:

```
debug1: channel 11: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 8080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 12: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 8080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 13: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 19: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
debug1: channel 19: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8080 for www.superuser.com port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 59380, nchannels 17
channel 20: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
debug1: channel 20: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8080 for www.superuser.com port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 59381, nchannels 16
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8080 for safebrowsing.google.com port 443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 59335, nchannels 15
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8080 for www.google.co.ve port 443, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 59385, nchannels 14
channel 13: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
debug1: channel 13: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 8080 for clients2.google.com port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 59391, nchannels 13
```

In the browser, I get net::ERR_TIMED_OUT.

Comment: Is there a proxy at home or not? Your question states both use an HTTP proxy but then says the difference at home is that there's no proxy.

Comment: At work where I want it to work there is a HTTP proxy with authentication. At home there is no proxy and it works ok.

Comment: Are you sure you're able to connect at all? Do you get a shell when you connect?

Comment: Yes I do get a shell and using netstat and the verbose parameter in ssh command I can see that the tunnel is created. But still I do not get Internet access.